# csv Jinja2 template render unicode error

Tags: python, csv, unicode, jinja2

I'm trying to render a jinja2 template with variables from a csv file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template('baseconfig.j2')

with open('C:\Users\\robertph\CompanyA.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in dictReader:
        hostname = row['hostname'] + '.txt'
        with open('C:\Users\\robertph\host_vars\\' + hostname,'w') as fh:
            fh.write(template.render(row))
```

But am getting the following error:

```
File ".\csv2dict_test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    fh.write(template.render(row))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 2042: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think I understand the error to be that I've got a unicode character `¦`  somewhere but I don't know where, although I've searched both the template & the dictReader.  I've read the docs (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#unicode) but don't understand how to mitigate this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character in question here is the [U+2013 EN DASH](http://codepoints.net/U+2013), and is part of your template; your CSV inputs are all ASCII bytestrings (otherwise Jinja2 would complain about them).

You can encode your template result:

```
fh.write(template.render(row).encode('utf8'))
```

or you can remove that fancy dash from your template file.

Jinja templates always render to a Unicode string, but Python 2 file objects require encoded strings. If you didn't see this happen before is because the implicit encoding to ASCII that takes place would succeed if it wasn't for the non-ASCII codepoint your template now includes.

Comment: I was looking for the wrong fancy character, but I found the guilty party and deleted it.  Adding `.encode('utf8')` also works, which is good to know.  Many thanks @Martijn